Density plot of a function and bar legend for a different function
I am trying to plot x^2+y^2=r^2 for a set of values of r and there is another function T=T(r). I want to create a density plot for x^2+y^2 which shows the bar legend for T as shown in the image, but r cannot be solved explicitly in terms of T. Is there any way to do that?
Thank You.

Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! Generally, it is advised that you include your concrete example (Mathematica code) in your question so that we do not speculate or assume something which is not there. But to answer your question: Yes, this is possible and not very difficult. For example, if you have a function $T(r)$: T[r_] := r^2 + Sin[r], then you can do InverseFunction[T] to get a function $r(T)$. But again: Please post the actual example :)

@Domen Thank you very much.
